# Replacing array elements in Javascript produces unexpected results

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to replace array elements (generic objects) with their alternatives (specific Objects), but objects within the original array remain unchanged.

```js
class SpecificObject{
}

this.Objects = [{},{}];

this.Objects.map((signer,index) => {
   //convert json generics to js objects
   this.Objects[index] = new SpecificObject(signer);
});

console.log(this.Objects);
```

Not sure if the code snippet illustrates the problem correctly, but what i expect to see is:

```
[
SpecificObject{},
SpecificObject{}
]
```

I even tried cloning the original object to do the iteration but it didn't help. Must be missing something stupid. Is there a way to achieve what i need with lodash?

**Edit**(followed the answer advise):
Now i do the following:

```
console.log('signers-before', this.Signers);
this.Signers.map(signer => new SigningTableSigner(signer));
console.log('signers-after',this.Signers);
```

And this is what i get in my log(object still remain generic):

[image]

**Edit2**

Oops, i forgot the assignment.  `this.Signers =`

now like this everything works as expected:

```
console.log('signers-before', this.Signers);
this.Signers = this.Signers.map(signer => new SigningTableSigner(signer));
console.log('signers-after',this.Signers);
```

Comment: Your code is correct. what is it logging?

Comment: Note the SO snippet console is not perfect. Open Chrome devtools (or similar) before you click **Run** and you should see the result you expect in the devtools console. (*[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWUgX.png)*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to modify the collection while you are iterating it.  Just return the object from the `map`.

```
this.Objects = this.Objects.map((signer,index) => new SpecificObject(signer));
```

Answer (score 2):

Map is used when you wants to return an array. You can just use forEach for what you are trying to do. But I think this will look better

```
this.Objects = this.Objects.map(signer => new SpecificObject(signer))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use `map` correctly. You should be just returning objects inside arrow functions. `map` actually returns new array, which contains elements which were created by applying function you have provided. Because of that you also have to reassign result ot `this.Objects`.

```
this.Objects = this.Objects.map(signer => {
   //convert json generics to js objects
   return new SpecificObject(signer);
})
```